# LinqKit Predicate Builder throws TypeLoadException?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, predicatebuilder, linqkit

I am experiencing a problem while attempting to execute a query that I have built dynamically using PredicateBuilder.

I am able to build the query but when executing the query itself I get the following "TypeLoadException"...

**When running:** `return context.SearchRecords.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();`

**Could not load type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.IDbAsyncEnumerable`1' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.**

I have been pulling my hair out with this for quite a while now, I have checked online examples etc and I seem to be doing everything correctly so I would expect this to work.

```
private IEnumerable<SearchDto> BuildAndExecuteQuery(string queryString)
    {
        var queryWords = this.GetQueryWordsFromQueryString(queryString);
        using (var context = new AlleyOopSearchContext())
        {
            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<SearchDto>();
            foreach (var word in queryWords)
            {
                var temp = word;
                predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.ShotDescription.Contains(temp));
            }

            return context.SearchRecords.AsExpandable().Where(predicate).ToList();
        }
    }
```

Project is built using .NET Framework 4.5 and uses Entity Framework 6.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more investigation I found the answer for myself, it turned out that anouther project within the solution was referencing a newer version of Entity Framework.

Upgrading all projects to the same version solved this issue.