# EntityFramework with ASP vNext

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm getting this error when I add EntityFramework to my project .

TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CultureAwaiter' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ErrorPageMiddleware.d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723533/linqkit-predicate-builder-throws-typeloadexception and see if the answer is applicable to your situation.

Comment: I don't use entity framework in another project from my solution  .  I get this error on every page of my website  even though i dont use Entity framework in my code yet .

Comment: TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'CultureAwaiter' from assembly 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.ErrorPageMiddleware.<Invoke>d__1.MoveNext()

Comment: Can you please share the `project.json` file?

Comment: project.json : http://pastebin.com/uEXV3vam

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci I Posted project.json . Can you take a look ?

Comment: Where did you post it?

Comment: @VictorHurdugaci Here: http://pastebin.com/uEXV3vam

Comment: You are using the `beta1` bits which are very old (probably 1 year old). Please update to `beta3` and see if you get the same error. Also, make sure that KRE/DNX matches the packages version.

Comment: I only have beta1 KRE available in project properties and if I install beta3 from nuget, it's not displayed as Target KRE Version .

Comment: I managed to install new KRE following this guid : https://cmatskas.com/asp-net-5-vnext-from-the-command-line/  . However, I had to manually copy kre-clr-win-x86.1.0.0-beta3 from C:\Users\Admin\.k\runtimes to C:\Users\Admin\.kre\packages afterwards .  I'm installing entity framework now to give it a try .

Comment: Actually it's not working . I get this error "Cannot find runtime package 'kre-clr-x86.-win-x86.1.0.0-beta3'. Please install the package using 'kvm install' " .  kvm install command doesnt work either  ... i get an error 400 Bad request